# How to check for route namespace in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

How to check for route namespace in Laravel similar to how the following code does?

```
{{ (Request::is('user*') ? 'active ' : '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can get a request segment:

```
{{ (Request::segment(1) == 'user') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

So `/user/username`, `/user/show` or `/user` etc, would all match.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information